# Why does the ternary operator work differently at compile time compared to the run time?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, ternary-operator

```
template <uint_fast64_t MAX_RAND>
    struct RandomLimit
    {
        static const uint_fast64_t steps =
            RAND_MAX >= MAX_RAND ? 
            1 : 
            RandomLimit<MAX_RAND / (RAND_MAX + 1)>::steps + 1;
    };
```

The code above yields and error; steps is undefined. At run time, if a function call would be in place of the last expression, this function would not be called and no side - effects would happen. Why isn't this code eliminated when the condition holds true?

Note that RAND_MAX is the cstdlib constant and I'm using a Visual Studio 2015 setup.

Comment: Nope. Compiles correctly, cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: Did you try instantiating the template? http://ideone.com/HONYBI

Comment: [MCVE] -- provide exact code that generates error, and exact **and full** error generated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably yours is a linker error, not a compiler error.

That is, the `steps` member is properly declared in a header file, so the code compiles fine, but then, if the condition is always true, then the compiler optimizes out the *else* expression and no reference to the `steps` variable is emitted. However, if the condition is not constant, then both branches are compiled, and you get an *undefined reference error*.

The solution, obviously, is to add the proper library to the linker command.

Comment: @MciprianM: Ahhh, that's why you should always copy the full error message! `fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900`, that's because you have a recursive template instantiation and exeed the maximum of 900 iterations!!!

Comment: actually in visual studio I got error C2065: 'steps': undeclared identifier so my question holds. But after all this I think I got my answer. The expression after ':' has to be compilable and it is not!